# Converting elements in char[] to int

Tags: c++, c++11

**Background:**

I have a communication between 2 machines (one plc and one computer running scripts written in c++). The PLC will send 16bits Int stored in a 4096 byte array.

The c++ code recive and store the data in

```
char data[4096];
```

I have tried different approaches to extract 2 bytes of a given position in data[] and store them in a external int but without success.
I don't need to handle big and small endian.

Comment: If you find "xa" in the two characters, what value would you expect in the int? For "08"? For "07"? Please decide on the language, because the answers wildy differ for C++ and C. (Since you ask very specifically about C++ and C++11, I will delete the C tag for you. Feel free to clarify yourself, with detailed reasoning in case of C AND C++.) Are you aware of sscanf() for C and of stringstreams for C++? You ask specifically about some easy way. Please demonstrate the non-easy way you have found. Please provide a [mre] providing initialised data and a suitable call to a suitably prototyped func.

Comment: Is it a string or an `int16_t`? Try `strtol` from `stdlib.h`?

Comment: @Neil That would probably not cover the two-character requirement. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Must have added C by mistake. I tried different approaches with memcpy() to simply move the data from data and into extractedInt but didnt get that to work.

Comment: maybe something like `int myInt = *((int16_t*)data[x]);`

Comment: It all depends on what your input is. `strtol(&"Hello 14 There."[6], 0, 0)` should give 14? (With appropriate error checking.)

Comment: @PatrickParker: On some processors, that would crash your program (though not on x86_64).

Comment: If your char array would just contain binary data, i. e. values in between [-128; 127] or [0; 255], depending on signedness of char type, you can combine via `int x = data[n] | data[n+1] << 8`, assuming little endian here. You can have unwanted effects due to sign extension on signed chars for negative values. This whole matter is safer if you do this with unsigned types (`unsigned char`, `unsigned int`).

Comment: @einpoklum character arrays are one of the types explicitly allowed by the standard to violate the strict aliasing rule. so not sure what you mean there.

Comment: To explain the backstory of the problem. I have a communication between a PLC and a computer that is using TCP to communicate with it.
The PLC send a chunk of 4096 bytes to the computer that have to read out the data.

The PLC will always place 16 bits integers meaning that the first int will be located in data[0], the second should be located in data[2] and so on

Comment: @einpoklum Not necessarily – if we always assure that addresses for this cast are even...

Comment: @MarcusKammarfelt You should add that comment to the question itself, it is pretty relevant.

Comment: Added to the first post so ppl know what why the weird question

Answer (score 2):

```
char data[4096];
//           ^  otherwise you have one incomplete 16-bit int!
```

In this case you indeed *might* use a hint from the comments, simply casting into a `int16_t` array:

```
auto numbers = static_cast<int16_t*>(data);
```

The array should be aligned correctly for such purposes already, to guarantee this you might use (since C++11):

```
alignas(2) char data[4096];
```

Still your PLC and your host machine might use different endianess, if so, you need to swap bytes for every `int16_t` value.